# Flex: accessing child through navigating the hiererachy

Tags: apache-flex, user-interface, hierarchy

I have a generic function to build rows of controls (each row comprising of sliders, radio buttons, reset buttons, text display) etc, and some functionality to change underlying data based on these

As I didn't want to write specific code for each row, I had code written by which I can detect the row on which there has been a mouseevent, and though the row access each individual control

The hierarchy used is titleWindow (part of popup)->skinnable container->HGroup->control

When I trace for a radiobutton, I get the path as follows           Electric_Modify.TitleWindowSkin2620._TitleWindowSkin_Group1.contents.contentGroup.0.RadioButton2645

The '0' before the radioButton stands for the first Hgroup id->named as 0

I tried accessing the radio button as follows- 5th element in the HGroup
((this.contentGroup.getChildAt(row)as Group).getChildAt(4) as RadioButton).enabled=false;

and get a message  "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference" on this line. How should I navigate the hierarchy to reach the element?

Comment: I don't know what kind of application you're creating with all these questions, but I can tell you right now you seem to like overly complicated solutions to a fairly easy problem.  Is there a reason you're not using a DataGroup or a List? item renderers? Data driven approach? separation of concerns?

Comment: @J_A_X Maybe he gets paid per each line of code written.

Comment: @Jason Towne, Haha, if only that were the case I'd know too many millionaires :P

Comment: @Jason: I wish that were the case!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@drkstr

Thanks for your input... I thought of an alternate approach that worked for me...I mapped out the parent of the HGroup via

parent1=hgrp.parent; and then referenced these buttons as follows

((parent1.getChildAt(row)as Group).getChildAt(4) as RadioButton)

This works like a dream...I presume your suggestion would let me jump across the intermediate layers

@J_A_X/ @Constantiner: Thanks for the suggestion. I have no idea why we didn't think through and go down the DataGroup path. Prima facie seems simpler... we got to creating the UI controls in MXML laying out controls serially,and when it came to making it generic, we literally replicated the MXML approach in AS. Started off easy, till it caused problems like above. We will fix this to a better approach, when we upgrade versions. It works for now

Answer (score 1):

You should be using getElementAt(...) and not getChildAt(...).

The get element functions represent a "higher level" element hierarchy which is needed to make skinning easier.

```
((this.getElementAt(row) as IVisualElementContainer).getElementAt(4) as RadioButton).enabled = false;
```

It should look something like that, but the exact hierarchy depends on what's in your app.